# JS reduce list based on one of its properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, list, reduce

I am writing a piece of method in react js, say I have a list like below.

```
const itemList = [
    {
        "id": 3295042,
        "tillPoint": "A",
        "date": "23/01/2019",
        "AnnaIncome": 100,
        "PeterIncome": 50,
        "KenIncome": 100,
        "freeCash": 30
    },
    {
        "id": 3295042,
        "tillPoint": "B",
        "date": "23/01/2019",
        "AnnaIncome": 300,
        "PeterIncome": 200,
        "KenIncome": 100,
        "freeCash": 50
    },
    {
        "id": 3295042,
        "tillPoint": "A",
        "date": "22/01/2019",
        "AnnaIncome": 120,
        "PeterIncome": 120,
        "KenIncome": 30,
        "freeCash": 50
    },
    {
        "id": 3295042,
        "tillPoint": "B",
        "date": "22/01/2019",
        "AnnaIncome": 100,
        "PeterIncome": 150,
        "KenIncome": 50,
        "freeCash": 60
    },
]
```

I wish to do a `.reduce` in order to make the list contain less items just by date property. 
For example, in above list, there are only actually two dates 22/01/2019 and 23/01/2019.
I wish to cut down the size of the list by each object's date. So each person's income would add together under its own name. 
Eventually, the list would become only 2 objects. And some property is removed in the new list
e.g below, 'id' and 'tillpoint' is removed, and the rest of the properties sum together:

```
let itemList = [
    {
        "date": "23/01/2019",
        "AnnaIncome": 300,
        "PeterIncome": 250,
        "KenIncome": 200,
        "freeCash": 80
    },
    {
        "date": "22/01/2019",
        "AnnaIncome": 220,
        "PeterIncome": 280,
        "KenIncome": 80,
        "freeCash": 110
    }
]
```

What I have tried here is something like below, but it is not working.

```
itemList.reduce((a, b) => ({ date: a.AnnaIncome + b.AnnaIncome, a.PeterIncome + b.PeterIncome, a.KenIncome + b.KenIncome, a.freeCash + b.freeCash }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```js
const itemList = [
    { "id": 3295042, "tillPoint": "A", "date": "23/01/2019", "AnnaIncome": 100, "PeterIncome": 50,  "KenIncome": 100, "freeCash": 30 },
    { "id": 3295042, "tillPoint": "B", "date": "23/01/2019", "AnnaIncome": 300, "PeterIncome": 200, "KenIncome": 100, "freeCash": 50 },
    { "id": 3295042, "tillPoint": "A", "date": "22/01/2019", "AnnaIncome": 120, "PeterIncome": 120, "KenIncome": 30,  "freeCash": 50 },
    { "id": 3295042, "tillPoint": "B", "date": "22/01/2019", "AnnaIncome": 100, "PeterIncome": 150, "KenIncome": 50,  "freeCash": 60 },
];


var new_itemList=[];

for(var key in itemList){
 var new_key = -1;
 for(var keyn in new_itemList){
    if(new_itemList[keyn].date == itemList[key].date){
       new_key = parseInt(keyn, 10);
    }
 }
 if(new_key == -1){
  new_itemList.push({'date':itemList[key].date, 'AnnaIncome': itemList[key].AnnaIncome, 'PeterIncome': itemList[key].PeterIncome, 'KenIncome': itemList[key].KenIncome, 'freeCash': itemList[key].freeCash});
 }else{
       new_itemList[new_key].AnnaIncome +=  itemList[key].AnnaIncome;
       new_itemList[new_key].PeterIncome +=  itemList[key].PeterIncome;
       new_itemList[new_key].KenIncome +=  itemList[key].KenIncome;
       new_itemList[new_key].freeCash +=  itemList[key].freeCash;
 }
}
console.log(new_itemList);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to group by date, which can easily be done using a hashtable:

```
 const byDate = new Map;

 for(const { date, id, tillPoint, ...rest } of itemList) {
   if(byDate.has(date)) {
     const dupe = byDate.get(date);
     for(const [k, v] of Object.entries(rest))
       dupe[k] += v;
   } else {
     byDate.set(date, { date, ...rest });
   }
}

const result = [...byDate.values()];
```

For sure you can easily hardcode the additions as `dupe.something += rest.something` if performance matters that much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator.

So here what i am doing is i am taking the dynamic properties which you want to add directly to your output without any manipulation in `...rest` and remaining i am taking out respective names.

Than i check if the data key is already there i add the `...rest` and add `freeCash` to existing value. If not there than we create a new key with the date and respective value.

```js
const itemList = [{"id":3295042,"tillPoint":"A","date":"23/01/2019","AnnaIncome":100,"PeterIncome":50,"KenIncom":100,"freeCash":30},{"id":3295042,"tillPoint":"B","date":"23/01/2019","AnnaIncome":300,"PeterIncome":200,"KenIncom":100,"freeCash":50},{"id":3295042,"tillPoint":"A","date":"22/01/2019","AnnaIncome":120,"PeterIncome":120,"KenIncom":30,"freeCash":50},{"id":3295042,"tillPoint":"B","date":"22/01/2019","AnnaIncome":100,"PeterIncome":150,"KenIncom":50,"freeCash":60},]

const op = itemList.reduce((output,current)=>{
  let {id,tillPoint,date,freeCash,...rest} = current
 
  if(output[date]){
    output[date] = {
      ...output[date],
      ...rest,
      date,
      freeCash: output[date].freeCash +freeCash
    }
  } else {
    output[date] ={
      ...rest,
      date,
      freeCash
    }
  }
  return output
},{})

console.log(Object.values(op))
```

Comment: Curious what the downvote was for, seems like a reasonable answer to me that demonstrates use of reduce.